# Chrome DevTools workspace кодировка

Tags: google-chrome, кодировка, google-chrome-devtools

Использую workspace в Chrome DevTools, если менять css через вкладку Elements/ Styles, 
то кириллица в файле сохраняется с неправильной кодировкой: ÃƒÆ’Ã‚ÂÃƒâ€šÃ‚Â¿ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬ËœÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â.
Если редактировать через вкладку Sources/Network то все нормально.
Не нашел где установить нужную кодировку. Или это можно исправить по другому?

Comment: какой редактор кода используете ? думаю вам в помощь подойдет Notepad+ так есть возможность изменить кодировка самого файлы. поставить например UTF-8

Comment: Это баг DevTools. Аналогичная проблема при добавлении проекта в Workspace. Работа в Workspace с файлами с кодировкой, отличной от UTF-8, приводит к появлению кракозябров. В Sources/Network работает корректно. Пишите багрепорт, проблема известная, но никто править не хочет.